# Library for solving system of linear equations with tridiagonal matrix?

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, differential-equations, linear-equation

I am modelling physical system with heat conduction, and to do numerical calculations I need to solve system of linear equations with tridiagonal matrix. I am using this algorithm to get results: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm But I am afraid that my method is straightforward and not optimal. What C++ library should be used to solve that system in the fastest way? I should also mention that matrix is not changed often (only right part of the equation is changed). Thanks!

Comment: Did you implement your own or are you using a library already?

Comment: I have implemented my own: simply coded the algorithm, only using the fact that matrix is not changing to do some precalculations.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Comment: To my knowledge, Eigen doesn't yet have the concept of tridiagonal or band matrices yet. You can still make a dense matrix and solve that but not sure it would be efficient

Answer (score 1):

The performance of this algorithm is likely dominated by floating-point division. Use SSE2 to perform two divisions (of c<sub>i</sub> and d<sub>i</sub>) at once, and you will get close to optimal performance.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth looking at the LAPACK and BLAS interfaces, of which there are several implementation libraries. Originally [netlib](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/) which is open-source, and then other such as MKL that you have to pay for. The function [dgtsv](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/520979?language=en) does what you are looking for. The open-source netlib versions don't do any explicit SIMD instructions, but MKL does and will perform best on intel chips.